# Validation always fails in bootstrap4 typehead in angular 2 even if value is selected

Tags: angularjs, angular, bootstrap-4

I am creating a form where i need to add bootstrap typehead for auto complete functionality.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.brand" [typeahead]="model.brands" ng-model-options="{'updateOn': 'blur'}"
        (typeaheadOnSelect)="brandOnSelect($event)" (typeaheadNoResults)="brandNoResults($event)"
        [typeaheadOptionField]="'Value'" class="form-control" ngcontrol="brand" >
        <div *ngIf="brand.dirty && !brand.valid ">
            <p  *ngIf="brand.errors.required" class="text-help">{{ required | translate }}</p>
        </div>
```

But the vaalidations are alws failed even if i select value from the list.
enter image description here
[image]

but the values are updated in model as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 ngcontrol="brand"
```

should be

```
 ngControl="brand"
   ^
```

Comment: Thankyou Günter Zöchbauer,

but after adding ngControl="brand"

i am getting new error message as follows.

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for NgModel! (Typeahead -> NgModel)
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js
Line 23501

Comment: Looks like `Typeahead` is not compatibel with `ngControl`. It seems to use `NgModel` inappropriately. It should use a `ControlValueAccessor` instead.