# No provider for NgModel! (Typeahead -> NgModel) exception when adding ngControl to bootstrap 4 TypeHead angular 2

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add ngControl form validation to bootstrap 4 typehead control in Angualr js 2.
code is as follows.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.brand" [typeahead]="model.brands" ng-model-options="{'updateOn': 'blur'}"
        (typeaheadOnSelect)="brandOnSelect($event)" (typeaheadNoResults)="brandNoResults($event)"
        [typeaheadOptionField]="'Value'" class="form-control" ngcontrol="brand" >
        <div *ngIf="brand.dirty && !brand.valid ">
            <p  *ngIf="brand.errors.required" class="text-help">{{ required }}</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: As explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713702/validation-always-fails-in-bootstrap4-typehead-in-angular-2-even-if-value-is-sel this is likely to be a bug in typeahead

Comment: Did you add `FORM_DIRECTIVES` to `bootstrap` or components `directives`?

Comment: Yes Kemsky,
And validations are working fine on other text fields

Comment: I have the same issue with ng2 bootstrap typeahead...

Answer (score 2):

You have missed "name" attribute on input which is required to work ngModel properly.